# .htaccess with two subfolders (bedrock in it self directory in the root)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

In the webroot of my local server, I try to install Bedrock in it self directory :

```
|- htdocs
   |- bedrock
      |- web
```

With the .htaccess file I wrote, I can access the web directory and so launch my application :

```
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.local$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bedrock/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bedrock/web/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.local$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ bedrock/web/index.php [L]
```

However I would like to avoid accessing to bedrock directory with the url : `example.local/bedrock`.

Can I do this with rewrite module from Apache or do I have to add a .htaccess with `deny from all` in the bedrock directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block direct access to the `/bedrock` subdirectory, but still allow requests be internally rewritten to that directory, by adding the following *before* your existing rules:

```
# Block "direct" access to the "/bedrock" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^bedrock($|/) - [F]
```

The above will return a "403 Forbidden" if `/bedrock` or `/bedrock/<anything>` is requested directly by the client.

By checking that the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is *empty* we can make sure the rule is only applied to direct requests (and not rewritten requests - later in the file).

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` env is empty on the initial request, but set to `200` (as in 200 OK status) after the first successful rewrite.

> ...or do I have to add a .htaccess with deny from all in the bedrock directory ?

That would block *all* requests, including your internal rewrites.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.local$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bedrock/web/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bedrock/web/$1
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.local$
> RewriteRule ^(/)?$ bedrock/web/index.php [L]
> ```

You should include the `L` flag on the first 2 rules. You've only included the `L` flag on the last rule (where it isn't strictly required).

You don't need the capturing group in the last rule. `^/?$` (or even `^$` in `.htaccess`) would suffice.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information.